# how to access to requests response in xmlns namespace webservices?

Tags: python, json, xml, python-requests, xml-namespaces

there is a web service that returns something like this and I want to access ***id*** in this response.what should I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"id":"1819","responseCode":"0","responseMessage":"0"}</string>
```

also, my function is here :

```
import requests
def sen_request():
    url = "somewhere.com/somewhere.asmx/new_one"
    payload = {}
    headers= {}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
    return (response)
```

- I try to access response in JSON with *response.json()* but accord this error:

> ```
> Exception Type:   JSONDecodeError
> Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code uses the json  lib and XML lib parsing in order to extract the id

```
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"id":"1819","responseCode":"0","responseMessage":"0"}</string>'''

data1 = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="tempuri.org">{"id":{"id1":"1819"},"responseCode":"0","responseMessage":"0"}</string>'''

root = ET.fromstring(data)
print(json.loads(root.text)['id'])

root = ET.fromstring(data1)
print(json.loads(root.text)['id']['id1'])
```

output

```
1819
1819
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. if id is a string like here 1819, its work. but when id is a dict like {'id1':2} it just prints"id1"

Comment: @Saeed Please share an example.

Comment: for ex: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"id":{"id1":"1819"},"responseCode":"0","responseMessage":"0"}</string> with your method that replyed prints only id1 and not shows 1819

Comment: @Saeed if the dict structure is different the way you look for `id`  MUST be different. I have updated the code and now it support your example.